# Saving objects to Storage -- what is a "file-like object"? (Descartes Labs)

Tags: descartes-labs-platform

I am trying to save a numpy array, the output of a Descartes Labs Platform Workflows pipeline, to Storage. The [docs](https://docs.descarteslabs.com/descarteslabs/client/services/storage/readme.html#descarteslabs.client.services.storage.Storage.set) for `storage.set` and `storage.set_file` state that the second argument should be a file name or "file-like object". However, when I call `storage.set(fname, X)` where `X` is the numpy array, I get the error:

`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

The same happens when I try to save a GeoDataFrame.

What should the object's type be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pickle.dumps` to create a file-like object that will work appropriately with these methods. When using `set_file`, you can also point to the path of the local file.

The below code blocks show how you can use both `storage.set` or `storage.set_file` to store objects and files into DL Storage, then `storage.get` or `storage.get_file` to get those objects and files from DL Storage.

Using `storage.set` and `storage.get`:

```
import descarteslabs as dl
import pickle
import numpy as np

storage = dl.Storage()

# treat array as a file-like object
storage.set('fname.npy', pickle.dumps(np.random.random((3, 3))))
my_array = pickle.loads(storage.get('fname.npy'))
```

Using `storage.set_file` and `storage.get_file`:

```
import descarteslabs as dl
import numpy as np

storage = dl.Storage()

# write the array to disk first and get it from tasks later
my_array = np.random.random((3, 3))
np.save('/cache/fname.npy', my_array)

# save in storage with identifier 'key_name'
storage.set_file('key_name', '/cache/fname.npy')

# get the file later from storage
storage.get_file('key_name', 'local_dir/fname.npy')
my_array = np.load('local_dir/fname.npy')
```